# How to get notification of mouse and keyboard use in Mac when app is running in background?

Tags: macos, cocoa, desktop-application

I am new in Mac Application development. I have a task to do, i have to identify whether user is using mouse/keyboard or not and that should be done when app is running in minimized state. I did some google but did not get the right way to do that.
Please suggest me a way how to achieve it.
Thanks in advance.

I want to add more precise information in this. Basically my requirement is that when my app is in minimised state, and i want to track wheather user is using Keyboard/mouse or not anywhere in the system/ or in any other application. How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in your applicationDidFinishingLaunching: method

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

    NSLog(@"key down");
    // Your code on key down event here

}];


[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

    NSLog(@"mouse down");
    // Your code on left mouse down event here

}];
```

Comment: Thanx Neha for ur reply !! From the code u provided i am getting the mouse event from in and out side the application. But m not getting any for keystrokes for either in/out side the application.

Comment: This will give notification of both mouse down and key down when your application is not the frontmost (key down and mouse dow on any other application including desktop but when the menubar is not showing your app's menu)

Comment: If you also want to handle notifications on your application, you have to handle its mouseDown: and keyDown event too.

Comment: But neha m getting mouse events but not getting keydwon event notification.I am doing the same as you mentioned. Can you tell me what could be the reason.

Comment: You are getting mouse events because once you click anywhere outside your application, other app comes to focus.

Comment: Aren't you getting key down event if you key down on any other application's window?

Comment: if i am doing keydown keeping desktop in focus then m not getting the keydown notification in my app which should come as we are using global notification.

Comment: But the time if you see the menu bar, it will be showing your app's menu because even after getting minimized its the frontmost app. Try setting the app to back when you minimize you window

Comment: Can u give me the way to set the app in back in minimised state ?

Answer (score 1):

NSEvent's `-addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` will let you do that.

Comment: Thanx Gerd K for ur kind response :) !! M Not getting any event notification in handler block of -addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler: method. I have added this method in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions. But when my app in on system tray or in minimized state, I am not getting any event notification.

Comment: Your post is flagged "osx" and "desktop-application". `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a UIApplicationDelegate Protocol method, only used on iOS. So which is it? If you are on the desktop then this method is never called, which a simple `NSLog` could have showed you. You should be using `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` instead.

Comment: OPPS my mistake :) !! Actually it is applicationDidFinishLaunching: m using, mistakenly i post ios UIApplication delegate method instead. Gred Can you tel me the way how to send Application in back when it is in minimised mode to receive the keyboard evnets from out side the application.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you want to hide it? NSApplication has a `-hide:` method. Global event filters should still receive events even when the app is hidden.

Comment: Actually i used the method (mentioned in Neha's reply)to receive global events even when app is in minimised state. I am getting events notification for mouse but not getting the key down event notification from outside the application. Do you any idea whats the issue in this or can sugges any other way to do it.